# nginx kill my threads

Tags: nginx, apache-zookeeper

I developed a nginx module to connect zookeeper, but I find the threads that created on zookeeper init were killed by nginx.  When I debug by gdb with 'info threads', it only shows one thread, but it should be three threads. Why is this and how can I solve it?